# uwsgi difference --wsgi-file and --file

Tags: uwsgi

What's the difference between the `wsgi-file` and `file` option in `uwsgi`? I know that `wsgi-file` comes with the python plugin package and `file` is a standard option with `uwsgi`.

Few things I noticed when creating a Flask app with uwsgi:

**this works:**
`$ uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031  --plugins=python2  --file /srv/http/site/run.py --callable app`

**this doesn't:**
`$ uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031  --plugins=python2  --wsgi-file /srv/http/site/run.py --callable app`

giving `unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)`

**and this does:**
`$ cd /srv/http/site` with

`$ uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031  --plugins=python2  --wsgi-file run:app`

my setup looks like this:

`site
    /run.py
    /app
        /__init__.py
        /static
            /style.css
        /templates
            layout.html
            index.html
            login.html
            ...`

Apparantly, the `wsgi-file` option can't work with an absolute path and callable, or am I missing something big?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, simply adding a `--chdir` to the project folder fixes everything.